# Find last occurrence of comma in a string using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which represents an address in Javascript, say, "Some address, city, postcode".

I am trying to get the 'postcode' part out.

I want to use the split method for this. I just want to know a regex expression that will find the last occurrence of ' , ' in my string.

I have tried writing expressions such as

```
address.split("/\,(?=[^,]*$)/");
```

and

```
address.split(",(?=[^,]*$)");
```

But these don't seem to work. Help!

Comment: maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/25658003/4573839

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use `.split()` just split on `","` and take the last element of the resulting array:

```
var postcode = address.split(",").pop();
```

If you want to use regex, why not write a regex that directly retrieves the text after the last comma:

```
var postcode = address.match(/,\s*([^,]+)$/)[1]
```

The regex I've specified matches:

```
,          // a comma, then
\s*        // zero or more spaces, then
([^,]+)    // one or more non-comma characters at the
$          // end of the string
```

Where the parentheses capture the part you care about.

Answer (score 5):

`pop()`   will remove the last element of an array:

```
address.split(",").pop()
```

you can use this

Comment: Thats a good way of going about it!

However I came up with this! : 
var comindex = address.lastIndexOf(",");
var half1 = address.substring(0,comindex);
var half2 = address.substring(comindex,full.length);

Answer (score 4):

With double quotes it is treating it as string

Use it this way

```
 address.split(/,(?=[^,]*$)/);
```

Or

This is more readable

```
 var postcode=address.substr(address.lastIndexOf(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var m = /,\s*([^,]+)$/.exec('Some address, city, postcode');
if (m) {
    var postcode = m[1];
}
```